# how to call WebClient methods inside Mono/Flux?

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I'm new to reactive programming
I call the "post" webclient method inside "mailTemplateMappinRepository.map()" in order not to interrupt the chain and pass the necessary parameters (data) to the "post" method

I'm not sure if this is a good practice and if I need to call .subscribe() for the "post" method

```
    return mailTemplateMappingRepository
        .findById(request.getTemplateKey())
        .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(new MailTemplateNotSupportedException(
            "The template with key " + request.getTemplateKey() + " is not supported!!!")))
        .map(t -> {
          log.info("sendEmailWithRetry: request {}", request);
          log.info("sendEmailWithRetry: templateMappings {}", t);

          if (!businessUnitAuthTokens.containsKey(t.getExactTargetBusinessUnit())) {
            updateBusinessUnitToken(t);
          }

          String token = "Bearer " + businessUnitAuthTokens.get(t.getExactTargetBusinessUnit());
          String uri = exactTargetMessageDefinitionSendsUrl.replace("{key}", t.getExactTargetKey());
          Map<String, Object> mailTriggerPayload = generateMailTriggerPayload(request);

          RetryBackoffSpec is401RetrySpec = Retry.backoff(1, Duration.ofSeconds(2))
              .filter(throwable -> throwable instanceof Unauthorized)
              .doBeforeRetry(retrySignal -> {
                log.error("UNAUTHORIZED... WILL TRY AGAIN... Request: " + request);
                updateBusinessUnitToken(t);
              })
              .onRetryExhaustedThrow((retryBackoffSpec, retrySignal) ->
                  new ExactTargetException(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value(), retrySignal.failure().getMessage(),
                      "There is something wrong with the authorization key for business unit: "
                          + request.getTemplateKey())
              );

          return restClientService.post(uri, mailTriggerPayload, token, String.class)
              .onErrorResume(error -> {
                if (error instanceof ExactTargetException) {
                  return Mono.error(new ExactTargetException(((ExactTargetException) error).getStatus(),
                      ((ExactTargetException) error).getBody(),
                      "Exact Target has errors... Status: " + ((ExactTargetException) error).getStatus()
                          + " Entity: "
                          + ((ExactTargetException) error).getBody()));
                }
                return Mono.error(error);
              }).retryWhen(is401RetrySpec).subscribe();
        });
  }
```

Are there any examples of applications or any other information on this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right about calling `subscribe()` in the middle of your chain. Don't do that.

```
.map()
```

semantically assumes that you want to map your object to another object or to change something within that object. This operation is synchronous.

However, `WebClient` calls return `Publisher` (some "promise") that can be either `Mono` or `Flux`

That means you should call it within `.flatMap()` that is asynchronous.

```
.flatMap()
```

Takes an object and returns some `Publisher`. So you should wrap your WebClient call to `.flatMap()` and you don't need to subscribe inside this operator.